# Providing input files during compilation

Tags: input, command-line

To run a CUDA C program we build the program and then run the binary file created from the command line as

```
/.prgm_bin_file
```

If for example the program needs some input files like for programs to image processing, I want to supply the data files or the input files at the time of compilation.

How can I do that. How the above command can be edited to give the required files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you supply the file names as arguments to main?

Comment: how is this question related to CUDA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program opens data files to use for input, it's using some file I/O API to do so.  For example, one possible method is to use [fopen](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html).

Just to use it as an example, if you are using `fopen`, it expects a filename (a character string) passed as the first parameter.

Many programs will take this filename from a the command line used to invoke the program.  But there's nothing that would prevent you from hard-coding the filename:

```
fp=fopen("mydata", "r");
```

In that case, the program would always attempt to open the file `mydata`

But if your program is already designed to use the filename as a command line parameter, it's not clear that this is any more useful than just invoking your program that way:

```
./prgm_bin_file  mydata
```